# 403 error when accessing bit.ly API to shorten URL with Python

Tags: python, bit.ly

Here's the code I'm using:

```py
import re
import sys
import glob
import json
import requests
import os
from pprint import pprint

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    urls_json = sys.argv[1]
else:
    urls_json = "enlaces.json"

with open( urls_json ) as data_file:
    urls = json.load(data_file)

api_key = os.environ["BITLY_TOKEN"]
group_guid = os.environ["BITLY_USER"]

shortened_links = []
for u in urls:
    payload = json.dumps({'long_url': u[1], "domain": "bit.ly", "group_guid": group_guid })
    print(payload)
    response = requests.post( "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten",
                              data=payload,
                              headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {api_key}" } )
    pprint(vars(response.raw))
    pprint(vars(response.request))
```

This consistently returns a 403 forbidden. The header is correct but I'm not so sure about the group_guid; I'm using my username for that. I obtained the token by issuing a curl request to the API. Any idea? Is this correct?

Comment: try `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`. Not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: @Poojan but `payload` is already in JSON...

Comment: What @Poojan said but feed it your dict directly. (json.dumps() not needed)

Comment: @Ph3n0x same 403 error.

Comment: Not sure why you thought group_guid expects a username. It's not a group and it's not a GUID, and the authorization header already identifies you.

Comment: @JJJ actually, it's also the name of the default group, equal to the username. I didn't find another way to get the actual (maybe numeric) ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just eliminate the `group_guid`:

```
    payload = json.dumps({'long_url': u[1], "domain": "bit.ly" })
```

Despite being clearly indicated in  [the API documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html#operation/createBitlink) as one of the parameters. That returns a 201 for "Created"

Comment: This worked, crazy that Bitly's Documentation doesn't mention that

Answer (score 1):

```
headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {api_key}" }
```

should be

```
headers={'Authorization': f"{api_key}" }
```