# Bit.ly gives 404 from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, bit.ly

I am trying to shorten URLs from Google Apps Script, but I keep getting 404 errors and I don't know why. Please help.

```
function shortenUrl(longUrl){
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',  
    'payload' : JSON.stringify({
      "long_url": longUrl,
    }),
    //  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + BITLY_TOKEN,
//                'Host': 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten HTTP/1.1", options).getContentText();
}
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function shortenUrl(longUrl){
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify({
      "long_url": longUrl,
    }),
    //  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + BITLY_TOKEN} // Modified
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", options).getContentText(); // Modified
}
```

- For above script, please confirm whether `BITLY_TOKEN` is declared, again.

#### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Bitly API (4.0.0)](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/)

Comment: This seems to be an improvement - I no longer get a 404 error, now I get a 403/forbidden error. BITLY_TOKEN is declared, and I have checked it is correct via the Bitly site. Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: I have tried various different links but it is always the same, unless the link is very long, in which case it says 'invalid parameter long url' or something like that.

Comment: @Tim Freeman Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that when `BITLY_TOKEN` can be used, the script worked fine. So I think that the value of `longUrl` might not be able to be used for the API. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample value of `longUrl` for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I have tried it with the URL of this page ('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272091/403-error-when-accessing-bit-ly-api-to-shorten-url-with-python') and with 'http://www.google.com' to be as simple as possible. It was the full URL with the https but for some reason that is removed when I save my comment. Always 403 forbidden. Tried two different BITLY_TOKENs from two different accounts, both with links successfully created from the GUI. Be grateful if you can help in any way.